# Tension in the given situation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, string

[image]

Here  two equal masses $m$ are hanging. We have to find tension in wire AB and wire CD. Assuming the tension in wire be $T$, I can't figure out why the tension in CD is 2 times to that of in wire AB. A general approach to these type of questions will also be appreciated along with answer.

Comment: Hi Cyberax. Perhaps [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/659264/is-the-tension-amplified-by-the-number-of-turns-made-by-the-string/659267#659267) answer will help?

Comment: Yes thanks that helped .

Comment: No problems and good luck with your studies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now since a pulley is massless equation of motion $\sum F=ma$ becomes $\sum F=0$ so
Now call the other pulley E and other mass F.
For pulley:
$\sum F=T_{AB}+T_{CE}-T_{CD}=0$
So we get $T_{CD}=2T$

Answer (score 1):

We assume a massless pulley. In its free body diagram, the forces acting on it will be two upward tension forces and one downward tension force. The upward tension is different from the downward tension here as the strings are not the same.  In equations, it will be

$$T' = 2T$$
$ T'$= downward tension( or tension in CD)

$T$ = upward tension  (or tension in AB)